# How do I check visibility of an element with testing angular directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I am trying to write a simple test for my angularjs directive.

The directive wraps a `div` in another `div`, creates a second child to show "LOADING", and selects which child is visible using `$scope.ready`. So the original HTML might look like:

```
<loading>
  <div>This is my data</div>
</loading>
```

And the HTML after running the directive would look like:

```
<div>
  <div ng-show="ready">
    <div>This is my data</div>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="!ready">
    LOADING
  </div>
</div>
```

The directive works when run in browsers. I wrote a unit test (mocha+shouldjs, but could be fine with jasmine+expect) as follows:

```
describe('loading', function(){
    var scope, element, loading, wrapper, parent;
    beforeEach(function () {
    inject(function ($compile,$rootScope) {
            scope = $rootScope;
            wrapper = $($compile('<div id="a"><loading><div id="b">RUN</div></loading></div>')($rootScope));
            element = wrapper.find("#b");
            parent = element.parent();
            loading = wrapper.children("div").children("div:eq(1)");
    });
    });
  it('should wrap the element with loading', function(){
        wrapper.children("div").children("div:eq(0)").children("div")[0].should.equal(element[0]);
  });
    it('should create the loading element', function(){
        loading.html().should.eql("Loading");
    });
    describe('when ready is false', function(){
        before(function () {
            scope.ready = false;
        });
        it('should show the loading element', function(){
            loading.is(":visible").should.be.true;
        });
        it('should hide the actual element', function(){
            element.is(":visible").should.be.false;
        });
    });
    describe('when ready is true', function(){
        it('should hide the loading element', function(){
            loading.is(":visible").should.be.false;
        });
        it('should show the actual element', function(){
            element.is(":visible").should.be.true;
        });
    });
});
```

The transclusion works, all of the HTML is added and wrapped properly. But **no** elements are visible. Errors are (trimmed):

> Chrome 37.0.2062 (Mac OS X 10.9.5) directives loading when ready is false should show the loading element FAILED
>
> AssertionError: expected false to be true
>
> Chrome 37.0.2062 (Mac OS X 10.9.5) directives loading when ready is true should show the actual element FAILED
>
> AssertionError: expected false to be true
>
> Chrome 37.0.2062 (Mac OS X 10.9.5): Executed 7 of 7 (2 FAILED) (0.235 secs / 0.048 secs)

Note: yes, I included jQuery in my test suite, so I can do the above `element.is()` and similar. Of course, it isn't working, so a simpler way that actually works is always welcome.

UPDATE:

Based on the info below from @Esteban, I have it simplified, but it still does not work. Changing `$scope.ready = true` does not seem to get angular to process the element. Fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/L825ks1w/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using jasmine-jquery:

In the past I have used [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) and used the fixture system so that the elements will actually be added to DOM and you can test situations such as this. It also will clean up your DOM after every test for you, so no need to worry about a dirty DOM after every test.

See the updated example:

```
function ($compile,$rootScope) {
            scope = $rootScope;
            wrapper = $($compile('<div id="a"><loading><div id="b">RUN</div></loading></div>')($rootScope));
            element = wrapper.find("#b");

            jasmine.appendSetFixtures(element);

            parent = element.parent();
            loading = wrapper.children("div").children("div:eq(1)");
    });
```

Then to test you can do:

```
    describe('when ready is false', function(){
        before(function () {
            scope.ready = false;
        });
        it('should show the loading element', function(){
            expect(loading).toBeVisible();
        });
        it('should hide the actual element', function(){
            expect(element).not.toBeVisible();
        });
    });
```

### Alternative:

You can also also check the existence of the `ng-hide` class instead:

```
expect(loading.hasClass('ng-hide')).toBe(false);
```

Comment: So appendSetFixtures adds it? That is nice. I can see how jasmine-jquery has those shortcuts. What about on the testing side?

Comment: I took your advice to check 'ng-hide'. It actually appears to work... except that changing `scope.ready` to true seems to have no impact. Here is the fiddle, see that the flip doesn't appear to happen. http://jsfiddle.net/L825ks1w/6/

Comment: Never mind, dumb mistake on my part. And you did answer the core question correctly with `ng-hide`. I will mark it correct.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it! Yeah, always remember to run scope.$digest when modifying scope in unit tests :)